# DO i need to import yml files in app/config from individuals bundles in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I have main config file   `/app/config.yml`. Now i have `services.yml` in `myBundle/resources/config/services.yml`

Do i need toimport that file in `app/config` or system will automatically detect that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If your bundle includes a `DependencyInjection/MyExtension.php` that loads the YAML file: no. Otherwise you will need to explicitly import it.

Comment: how can i import services.yml from my bundle to `app/../config.yml`. i already have few services definitions in config.yml